# How do i pull elements out of this array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
>> events.first
    => #<Bandsintown::Event:0x1037caf98 @venue=#<Bandsintown::Venue:0x1037c9580 @region="Australia", @bandsintown_id="160698", @latitude="-37.8161090", @city="Melbourne Vic", @bandsintown_url="http://www.bandsintown.com/venue/160698", @longitude="144.9725040", @country="Australia", @name="Rod Laver Arena at Melbourne Park">, @bandsintown_id="3671194", @on_sale_datetime=nil, @artists=[#<Bandsintown::Artist:0x1037c9328 @bandsintown_url="http://www.bandsintown.com/Metallica", @mbid="65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab", @name="Metallica">], @ticket_status="available", @bandsintown_url="http://www.bandsintown.com/event/3671194", @ticket_url="http://www.bandsintown.com/event/3671194/buy_tickets", @status=nil, @datetime=Wed Sep 15 19:00:00 -0400 2010>
> events.first[:region]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Bandsintown::Event:0x1037caf98>
>> events.first.region
NoMethodError: undefined method `region' for #<Bandsintown::Event:0x1037caf98>
```

Am i missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`events` is not an array, it is an `Bandsintwon::Event` *object*. Furthermore, `region` is a *property* of `venue`, which is another object within `events`, of type `Bandsintown::Venue`. Without having the classes for reference, it's possible that there might be `venue` and `region` methods that you can use to get the `@venue` and `@region` instance variables:

```
events.first.venue.region
```

Failing that, you could use `instance_variable_get` to get the value directly:

```
region = events.first.instance_variable_get("@venue").instance_variable_get("@region")
```

... but it's probably better to use a method (so you should add one if it's your class and one doesn't exist!)

Answer (score 1):

```
events.first.venue.region
```